# Sharp knee pain when going up and down stairs/bending my knee after my first backpacking trip

Tags: backpacking, health, injury

This past weekend, I went on my first backpacking trip.  The last 5 miles were all straight down hill which caused a lot of knee pain.  Now, three days later, I still have excruciating, stabbing pain on the right side when bending my knee/applying pressure/going up and down stairs.  I have been icing my knee. What could this be and what should I be doing about it? Thanks!

Comment: Is the pain on the lateral side of your knee? And would you say it hurts more going down stairs?

Comment: If you have health insurance, I would suggest seeing a specialist!

Comment: Related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3846/3313

Comment: Go see a Dr? [I'm not sure the internet is the best place to get a solution to this](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/448/2766)

Comment: It is more of my kneecap, it feels like.  Kneecap is sore and the stabbing pain comes from both the medial and lateral sides of the knee.  Yes, it hurts the most going down the stairs.  I am in school, so it is hard to get to a doctor currently.  I am just looking for suggestions until I can get to a doctor.  Thanks!