# Sore left knee when hiking

Tags: hiking, injury

Hi I have been a keen cyclist and walker for many many years, but this year I have taken more to hiking, 2-6 miles walk which I really enjoy.

But this last 4 months I have started developing a persistent ache in my left knee especially at the back of the knee, it seems to be sore to the touch at the lower part of my left ham string and the upper part of my left calf.

when this happens I seem to be dragging my left leg for about 5-7 days then it seems to be ok for a while then after a week or so it starts again.

does any one experience this type of issue as I really miss getting out and about over the moors

Comment: Related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3846/what-is-this-knee-pain-when-going-downhill

Comment: What shoes are you wearing? Do you take a backpack? Do you use trekking poles? There's a lot of factors as to why you maybe experiencing pain, and how to solve it.

Comment: Can you explicitly state your question? As it is right now it is implicitly clear what you are asking, but there is no actual question. And as is now this seems to me very narrow question that is about your individual health and is thus not applicable in general.

Comment: There are all kinds of potential causes. If this is affecting your quality of life, I would strongly recommend a consultation with a skilled sports physiotherapist.