# Old fracture starts to hurt

Tags: hiking

I've had a fracture in my left leg about twelve years ago.

However, if I do a lot of stuff, like let's say Mo: 3D-archery, Tu: jogging, Wed: hiking, Th: jogging, this old fracture hurts a lot. Especially when my body starts to come down again. While I run (etc.) I don't feel anything but when my body starts to relax.

Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: This seems like a personal health question, which is a delicate topic and a solution for your specific problem will probably not be applicable in general. I feel like such questions should be off topic and we should allow only first aid questions.

Comment: @imsodin Hmmm... a similar question seems to be pretty popular http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3846/what-is-this-knee-pain-when-going-downhill

Comment: True, I think this needs further discussion. I started a meta question: http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/744/how-do-we-handle-health-related-topics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a diagnoses over the internet, will be very difficult if not impossible.

Comment: Only an expert on this topic that can physically examine your leg will be able to give you an educated prognosis.

Comment: If it was a nonunion you would have realized earlier (it does depend where on the leg, that is not even specified, but as a general rule...) An orthopedic assessment would be necessary to properly answer such a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a doctor (just a runner) but there are too many scenarios that could be factoring in. My top three guesses, would be the following:

**1) Get a lot of rest.**
It's surprising how long some seemingly basic injuries take. I'm still working through an ankle roll from two years ago, a tailbone injury took years... it's tough and often very frustrating but you need to be patient.

**2) Proper Shoes**
If you're flat footed you may need more supportive shoes. Hit a well-respected running store to have your foot and gate reviewed. Something like flat feet could lead to over pronate causing your leg to twist which may be impacting the injury. It may not show up during your run due to adrenaline covering any potential pain signals.

**3) It may not be fully healed**
Seriously. A close running buddy of mine is currently recovering from surgery from an injury ~15 years ago. He has been effectively running on a broken foot the entire time but it took a while to really impact him painfully. "Funny" part is that he eventually went to a doctor not for foot pain but because he was experiencing so much knee and hip pain.

In short: It may be an easy fix but hard to diagnose online.